# MSACCESS - How to trigger the Excel's import/export wizard via VBA (CommandBarButton)

Tags: vba, ms-access, commandbar

I have a form with a button that HAS to trigger the classic Excel's import/export wizard via VBA.

[image]

I tried to list all the `CommandBar` in order to identify the one i need and next the Excel's `CommandBarButton`, so i can use it for a function. i did like this:

```
Public Function ListCommBars()
Dim cbrBar As CommandBar
'Dim ctlBar As CommandBarButton
'Dim cbrBars As CommandBars
'Dim strVal As String

For Each cbrBar In CommandBars

    Debug.Print cbrBar.Name, cbrBar.NameLocal, cbrBar.visible
Next

End Function
```

but this function returns a list of bars i can't recognize on my current commandbars..
my goal is to call the Excel's import/export `CommandBarButton` and trigger it via VBA.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want:

`DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdExportExcel`

or

`DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdImportAttachExcel`

Calling CommandBars is deprecated method. Only time I've ever used it is for:
`CommandBars.ExecuteMso "DataRefreshAll"`

Comment: didn't know there's a DoCmd like that..sorry.. but anyway if i want to trigger another CommandBarButton how can i do that?

Comment: Explore DoCmd.RunCommand commands by simply reading the intellisense dropdown list as you type code or use the VBE Object Explorer.